# How to modify QCombobox current item using PaintEvent() in Qt

Tags: qt, combobox, qt4, paintevent

I have a Combobox which has 3 items i.e. Item 1, Item 2 and item 3. I added these 3 items in .ui file and also added an image each for all using a resource file. Now when I am running the application, it shows the first item in combobox along with a image towards left. When i click on dropdown, I can see all the items along with images.

What I basically want to do is just display the image in the combobox and when user clicks on dropdown, it should show the image and text too.

**Scenario:** Items and images inside Combobox are added as follows:

```
Image 1 Item 1
Image 2 Item 2
Image 3 Item 3
```

When I run the app, it should display in combobox as

`Image1`

since first item gets displayed by default. I think it can be done when painting the current selection, QCombobox uses a re-implantation : `void MyCombo::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)` which is something I am not aware of.

Can anyone help me in this?? :)

How can I achieve it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hould inherit a QComboBox and reimplement `void QComboBox::showPopup () [virtual]`
P.S. If you reimplement this function to show a custom pop-up, make sure you call hidePopup() to reset the internal state.
Second idea I have is to implement a model for combobox but i don't now exatly is there any roule for popup elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If i reimplement this function, it will show a custom pop-up. But what I want is to display only Image by default when I run the app. When I click Popup it should show everything which is happening.

Comment: Also there is a void QComboBox::setView ( QAbstractItemView * itemView ) which sets the view to be used in the combobox popup to the given itemView. The combobox takes ownership of the view.

Comment: I think ShowPopup() aint a right way to achieve it. `paintevent` is something which is used when app paints the current selection

Comment: I think you shuld add an list continer to store strings of items and when show popup setItemText(i,"...") for each item when hiding setItemText(i,"");